# Need help defining the theoretical covariance matrix between a parameter and two distinct estimators

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis, covariance-matrix, structural-equation-modeling, ranking

I have a problem that resembles SEM or factor analysis, but the indicators are estimators of the parameter, not empirical observations of random variables. The model is a one-factor model with two indicators, and I want to get the variance-covariance matrix. I know that a model like this is not identified, but the whole thing is purely theoretical/mathematical, so it seems like I might be able to compute the true/population matrix anyway.

Specifically, I have a parameter and two different estimators of it, and I want to define the relationships among them as the parameter varies from 0 to 1. The parameter is population correlation $\rho$, while the estimators are $r$ and $m$, where $r$ is the sample Pearson correlation for bivariate normal sample $(X, Y)$ of size $n$, and $m$ is the matching statistic, computed as the number of matching paired ranks $R(x_i) = R(y_i)$ between ranked $X$ and ranked $Y$.

This is what is known: the variance/standard error for $r$, as a formula in $n$ and $\rho$; and
the variance/standard error for $m$, computed as $np$, where $p$ is the probability of observing at least one match, which is a strictly increasing (but unknown) function of $\rho$. For what it's worth, I also know $corr(r,m) = (n-1)^{-2}$ when $\rho = 0$.

Edit: I suppose another wrinkle is that, because both indicators are computed on the same variables in the same sample, local independence is non-existent. In fact, the random variance in the data might be conceived as a second factor on which both indicators load.

Any help would be appreciated. Even bounding the covariances in the matrix could be extremely useful.